# Generating data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to generate data at random with a given mean and range. For example, generate a random set of data given with mean 15 and range 10 to 20.

So far, I've been able to generate data with a mean and given standard deviation, but this doesn't constrain the range.

```
NORM.INV(RAND(),15,5)
```

How would I go about generating the data to fit the constraints stated above? Note that I do not require that the data be normally distributed.

Comment: I meant 15, I've added that change.

Comment: Do you require *normal* distribution? by definition it has limits of -inf and +inf?

Comment: I don't require normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly if we pick values between 11 and 19. they will meet the constraints. So in **A1** through **A10**, enter:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(11,19)
```

In **A12** enter:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A10)
```

We must now normalize the data to force the mean to be exactly ***15***. In **B1** enter:

```
=A1*15/$A$12
```

and copy down.

**B1** through **B10** will fall between 10 and 20 and have an exact mean of 15:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a ***uniform distribution*** around a specified mean, `15`, but capped at a min of `10` and a max of `20`

```
=MAX(MIN(RAND()*15*2,20),10)
```

I don't agree with the use of the word "mean" here though, because if your intention is to use any other number than 15 with the same min and max, that new number will *not* be the mean

Comment: This constrains the data to 10 to 20, but does not generate the data around a certain mean always.

Comment: Please can you explain further? This will absolutely produce data with a mean of `15`. Is the issue that you want to be able to *specify* the mean?

Comment: Yes, I would like to specify the mean. Your formula can produce a dataset with a mean of 15, but not in every case.

Comment: I updated to allow you to specify the mean and the upper/lower limits. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: This is not quite what I want, but by a combination of the methods you presented I have some approximate data. As context, I am creating fake data to model on (necessary in this case). I have some theoretical distribution (for example, Variable1 must be mean = 15, range = [10,20], sample size = 100).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the random range that you're looking for, you can scale the values to fit accordingly:

=NORMINV(   ,    ,  )

=NORMINV((RANDBETWEEN(0,1)/10),15,5)

Comment: This generates a number error if the RANDBETWEEN function produces a 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would use VBA (Visual Basic for applications). It works like a more defined object based Visual Basic. If you are more keen on OOP than spreadsheets this might be the key to your problem.